How much effort to repair front porch footings/girders?
I had a home inspection done yesterday after moving in a couple of months ago, and he is concerned about the front porch and thinks it should be replaced/repaired soon. He thinks the work needed is a combination of pouring new footings and replacing the girders, but he recommended a professional contractor evaluation/repair. Does it appear as concerning as it was communicated to be?




Cost questions are off topic here. "Concern" is subjective. Please see [ask] and the [help], then see if you can revise to ask something more specific. I can't see Reddit on my network; please use a proper image host.

I get where you're coming from @isherwood, and missed the part of cost being off-topic. A better question is getting a sense of how large this kind of project is.
I understand that concern is subjective, however, the request for support is clearly stated and has been understood by others who have responded with helpful answers. In the future, I'll certainly try to phrase my questions better - this is a new world to me, and I don't know what I don't know. Thanks.

@isherwood - Thanks. I removed the cost question, but my fundamental question stays the same. If you have a recommendation for how I can rephrase it, please make it, since the fundamental meaning of the post remains the same.

We can't actually see the footings in these photos. The cast deck block seems to be resting on something more substantial than the ground. Is that the case? Also, what are "girders"? Do you mean the posts, or do you mean horizontal members in the floor or roof structures? Again, we need more clarity.

@isherwood - Thanks. I appreciate the hyperfocus on the composition of the post. English isn't my first language, so I can't get it all perfect every time. Since it's clear that you understand what's being asked, I'd appreciate your input. I don't have additional details other than "it looks concerning and warrants work". So yes, do you agree?

I'm referring to the cast deck block, which the inspector referred to as footings. There is nothing underneath these blocks. Yes, I mean the posts.

It is just on the soil

What did they do on the other side of the porch on the post by the stairs?

Do you know how it's attached to the house?

The wood posts look to be in good shape. They just need to be on a better
permanent footing.
It is possible that the porch can be raised an inch or so and footings can be poured. Then the porch lowered on to the footings.  This should not be a great expense.
Get a few contractors to look at the porch and get estimates for the work. Ask that the estimates outline in detail what work will be done. Then you can compare and choose.

I agree with this.   However just because an inspector says something should be replaced or work should be done doesn't mean it needs to be done right away and maybe never.      I mean the porch is 3 feet high and seems to be well built.   Just because we wouldn't put footings in like this doesn't mean they won't work well.   When I see something seemingly well made as the porch, I assume there may have been reasons for things like the ghetto footers.   We haven't even asked where he is at or if the porch has an movement.

Answers should suggest methods that are "best practice" and not guess at the viability of something working in a sustainable manner.   Regardless of the location, placing supports for a covered front porch on deck blocks is not the "best practice".  It is not up to us internet people to determine if it is common or legal in the OP's location. Anyone with any building experience would determine that given the situation, deck blocks are not the proper choice for a  foundation.

This could have been permitted and passed.    In some New England states I know this is perfectly acceptable because of the rocky soil.    I know you are giving best practice for most of the US but it should also be pointed out, that the porch was well made (from looking at it) and these footings could outlast the wood.

You are assuming the area is New England and assuming the inspector does not know his job.

The frost line where I am is 24". In Northern VA area. We weren't able to find any permits pulled. Inspector was pretty confident that permits weren't pulled for it

@RMDman - I mentioned that your answer was right.    I just think we go overboard on best practices especially in the world of engineering.   This isn't a safety issue.    The porch isn't going to drop 10' when you walk on it.    In fact it won't dramatically deteriorate so if the footings do start sliding or moving it will be very apparent over a long period of time.    If I lived here I would want what your answer is but I wouldn't bother because there is a very good chance these things could last forever and I can keep an eye on it.
